# get a list of top occurrence of specific event and exclude the other

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I am having an index where data is logged with a success/fail flag for a specific item.
I want to get a unique list of items who has fail and never a success. Usually a success is expected after fail from time perspective

Sample input

| Date | User | Status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Jan 01 | user1 | Fail |
| Jan 02 | User1 | Success |
| Jan 01 | User2 | Fail |
| Jan 02 | User2 | Fail |

Output would be only user2

Answer (score 0):

## Tldr;

I am not sure there are any easy way to do this, purely with `Elasticsearch`.
But you could get all status per user and then filter the one that have `success` in it.

## Solution

To set up:

```json
POST _bulk
{"index":{"_index":"75225454"}}
{"user":"user 1","status":"success"}
{"index":{"_index":"75225454"}}
{"user":"user 1","status":"success"}
{"index":{"_index":"75225454"}}
{"user":"user 2","status":"failure"}
{"index":{"_index":"75225454"}}
{"user":"user 2","status":"failure"}
{"index":{"_index":"75225454"}}
{"user":"user 3","status":"success"}
{"index":{"_index":"75225454"}}
{"user":"user 3","status":"failure"}
{"index":{"_index":"75225454"}}
{"user":"user 4","status":"failure"}
```

Here is the query

```json
GET /75225454/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "users": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "user.keyword",
        "size": 10
      },
      "aggs": {
        "status": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "status.keyword",
            "size": 10
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

you should get:

```json
{
  "took": 1,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 1,
    "successful": 1,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": {
      "value": 7,
      "relation": "eq"
    },
    "max_score": null,
    "hits": []
  },
  "aggregations": {
    "users": {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
      "buckets": [
        {
          "key": "user 1",
          "doc_count": 2,
          "status": {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
            "buckets": [
              {
                "key": "success",
                "doc_count": 2
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "key": "user 2",
          "doc_count": 2,
          "status": {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
            "buckets": [
              {
                "key": "failure",
                "doc_count": 2
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "key": "user 3",
          "doc_count": 2,
          "status": {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
            "buckets": [
              {
                "key": "failure",
                "doc_count": 1
              },
              {
                "key": "success",
                "doc_count": 1
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "key": "user 4",
          "doc_count": 1,
          "status": {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
            "buckets": [
              {
                "key": "failure",
                "doc_count": 1
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Now you just need to filter out users that have

1. `status.buckets > 1`
2. `status.buckets[0].key == 'success'`

And you should be good.